# how to run a Perl thread in for loop

Tags: perl

I have a multi-threaded main Perl script. What I want to do is each thread will have 3 commands to run, once the entire thread is completed, I want my script to fire same thread again, basically in a loop, can anyone let me know how to do this

this is my **perl code snippet**

```
my @finalOneClickarray= grep(/\S/, @oneclickConcurrentbackup); #----Removing the empty content from the array---#   

#---Making Concurrent OneClick backup commands using threads------#
my @threads;

#-----performing the CHO loops as given by user-------#
foreach (@finalOneClickarray) {
    push @threads, threads->new(\&concurrentBackupCommandsRead, $_);
}

foreach (@threads) {
    $_->join();
}
```

**concurrentBackupCommandsRead** is the method where commands get executed.

Updated perl code :--

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
my @arr = (1,2,3,4);
my $outnumber :shared =4;


print "\n variable outside thread that is in main program $outnumber\n";
my @threads;


for($i=0;$i<=3; $i++)
{
  print "\ncalling subrountine vinay for $i times\n";

  vinay();

}

sub vinay()
{
    foreach (@arr) {
       push @threads, threads->create(\&doSomething);
    }
    foreach (@threads) {
       $_->join();
    }
}

sub doSomething ()
{

 print "\n Before increment is $outnumber\n";
 my $foo = $outnumber; 
 $outnumber = $foo + 1;

print "\n After increment is $outnumber\n";

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to distribute the workload between a fixed number of threads? If so, use a Thread::Queue to pass tasks to the workers.

Comment: no each thread will execute the sub rountine and returns back to main perl script, now that, it has returned to main script, i want to fire same set of commands again, so this has to continue in loop, so wanted to ask how to put the above code into loop, if there is any way please let me know

Comment: @VinayD, unclear what you're asking.  Given your comment, why can't you simply put the above code in a subroutine and call *that* in a loop?  Show us what you've tried and why/where is doesn't work.

Comment: I have done that also, but i get the below message Perl exited with active threads:, having said that, my task is simple, once the above threads are created and joined, they executed they part and come back, once they come back i need to do the same job again and again, so i wanted this to happen in for or while loop, when i tried in for loop, it gave above message

Comment: @pilcrow, i have pasted my sample code, please let me know what is that i am doing wrong here....

Answer (score 1):

On your second run through the loop, you're trying to join an already joined thread (because you only ever add to `@threads`). This throws an error, "Thread already joined".

Clear `@threads`, or localize it to `vinay()`, eg.

```
sub vinay()
{
    my @threads;
    foreach (@arr) {
       push @threads, threads->create(\&doSomething);
    }
    foreach (@threads) {
       $_->join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in that case, i have an question, is that second time the threads which are getting spawned will start there process, only after the threads which got spawned in first loop are completed or even before they get completed its getting spawned.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you're asking if the second group of threads will run after the first group completes, the answer is yes. (Because your code enforces that behavior by waiting for them to return)

Comment: oh ok thats what i was asking, i wanted my first group of threads to complete and then only the second group of threads should be spawned, thanks a lot for your help..